# right alignment in the second line of an inline equation

Tags: equations

I have an inline equitation inside an item-environment.
The problem is to align the second line on the right side. How to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Theoretically, the calculated voltage should be
correspond to the measured voltage. But in practice it is
often \emph{not} the case. There are small deviations. Calculate first
the absolute deviations according to the rule:\\
\medskip{}\\
$\left\langle\text{absolute deviation}\right\rangle = \\ \left\langle\text{calc. value}\right\rangle - \left\langle\text{measured value}\right\rangle$\\
\medskip{}\\
The ,,measured value`` here is of course the ,,measured voltage``.\\
Calculate all absolute deviations and enter the results in the
table.
\item Further steps
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX is not a word processor. Usage of `\\` should be limited to where explicitly ending lines is necessary.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Theoretically, the calculated voltage should be
correspond to the measured voltage. But in practice it is
often \emph{not} the case. There are small deviations. Calculate first
the absolute deviations according to the rule:
\begin{multline*}
\langle\text{absolute deviation}\rangle = \\ 
\langle\text{calc.\ value}\rangle - \langle\text{measured value}\rangle
\end{multline*}
The ,,measured value`` here is of course the ,,measured voltage``.

Calculate all absolute deviations and enter the results in the
table.

\item Further steps

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I also removed `\left` and `\right` that do nothing useful in that formula.

[image]

Note `calc.\ value` in order to avoid an end-of-sentence period. It could also be `calc.\@ value`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a `\hfill` in front of the second line, but with a `\mbox{}` in front of it, because `\hfill` doesn't work at the very beginning of the line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Theoretically, the calculated voltage should be
correspond to the measured voltage. But in practice it is
often \emph{not} the case. There are small deviations. Calculate first
the absolute deviations according to the rule:\\
\medskip{}\\
$\left\langle\text{absolute deviation}\right\rangle = \\ \mbox{}\hfill \left\langle\text{calc. value}\right\rangle - \left\langle\text{measured value}\right\rangle$\\
\medskip{}\\
The ,,measured value`` here is of course the ,,measured voltage``.\\
Calculate all absolute deviations and enter the results in the
table.
\item Further steps
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As long as you're loading amsmath, you might as well use multline.  But there are several other problems with OP's code that have been fixed in the other answer.

Comment: I do not know the terminus "OP's code".

Comment: OP = original poster.  So there are several other problems with the original code that should also be fixed.  But I'm now seeing that you are the original poster, so I would encourage you to look through the other answer to see what else has changed.  At a minimum, you should use `\[...\]` instead of `\medskip{}\\$...$\medskip{}\\` if you're wanting to have an equation displayed by itself.